# Creating a new Email that is apart of a conversation in EWS

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send multiple emails under the same `ConversationId` so that they appear to be apart of the same conversation, you can't seem to directly set the `ConversationId`.

Documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-conversations-by-using-ews-in-exchange) suggests;

> Exchange defines conversations based on the Message-ID value of the
>   first email message in a thread. All replies and related messages
>   reference the original message's Message-ID header in their References
>   and In-Reply-To headers.

I tried doing this, so sending my second email with the `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers as the ID for the first email. The message details looked like this for the second email;

```
From: ********
To: **************
Subject: 2nd Email SendingAnEmailWithAMessageIdShouldBeOnTheSameConversation
Thread-Topic: 2nd Email
SendingAnEmailWithAMessageIdShouldBeOnTheSameConversation
Thread-Index: AQHUs6nYQZn4My04tkWAljb7cIRMpA==
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 16:58:36 +1100
Message-ID:
<DB6P195MB023219A79DF4430C4CB8D5AC829A0@DB6P195MB0232.EURP195.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
References:
<DB6P195MB02326884F08F83C932FB3A31829A0@DB6P195MB0232.EURP195.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
In-Reply-To:
<DB6P195MB02326884F08F83C932FB3A31829A0@DB6P195MB0232.EURP195.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-RecordReviewCfmType: 0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="_000_DB6P195MB023219A79DF4430C4CB8D5AC829A0DB6P195MB0232EURP_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_DB6P195MB023219A79DF4430C4CB8D5AC829A0DB6P195MB0232EURP_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

BODY - SendingAnEmailWithAMessageIdShouldBeOnTheSameConversation

--_000_DB6P195MB023219A79DF4430C4CB8D5AC829A0DB6P195MB0232EURP_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</head>
<body>
BODY - SendingAnEmailWithAMessageIdShouldBeOnTheSameConversation
</body>
</html>

--_000_DB6P195MB023219A79DF4430C4CB8D5AC829A0DB6P195MB0232EURP_--
```

But they end up with different `ConversationId's` and don't have that conversation 'feel' when looking at them within the UI.

Anyone managed to achieve this at all?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted the Thread-Topic doesn't look correct to me, the Thread-Topic should be set to the same value as the original email or the clients won't thread the email correctly.

Try setting the extended property for the Conversation Topic eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC_W = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0070, MapiPropertyType.String);
        email.SetExtendedProperty(PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC_W, "what topic");
```

Comment: That makes sense as the `ConversationTopic` value in the document says : `Contains a normalized form of the subject value that was set on the original message. This is the same as the Thread-Topic message header. This value is read-only.` but this is obviously set by Exchange at the point of sending, is just not picking up that the emails are related.

Comment: You can always set the underlying Mapi property for that see edit

Comment: DIdn't seem to do much/anything at all but further reading says you may need to set the Conversation_Index too, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/tracking-conversations if you go down this root.

Answer (score 0):

No exactly a perfect resolution but if you set the Subject as the same as the first email or you can seem to prepend `"RE: "` then it seems to thread the email, no ideal but does work.